# I'm trying to add Recyclerview in my apps. But I don't know what's wrong with my code?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm tring to add Recyclerview in my activity_main.xml

I have added some margin in shopping_item.xml but After trying to run my app margin was gone.
I tried to create new project but same issue with recyclerview. I don't know how to fix this!

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/shopping_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/shopping_item" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my shopping_item.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivDelete"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
      />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPlus"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvAmount"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
       />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMinus"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_minus"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvAmount"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ivPlus"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is activity_main.xml.Items of recyclerview looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2qJH.png)

[After successfully running my Application and look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUsO5.jpg)

This is my MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val database = ShoppingDatabase(this)
    val repository = ShoppingRepository(database)
    val factory = ShoppingViewModelFactory(repository)
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[ShoppingListViewModel::class.java]


    val adapter = ShoppingItemAdapter(listOf(), viewModel)

    binding.shoppingRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.shoppingRecyclerview.adapter = adapter

    viewModel.getAllShoppingItems().observe(this, {
        adapter.item = it
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })


    binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
        ShoppingItemDialog(this, object : AddDialogListner {
            override fun onAddButtonClicked(item: ShoppingItem) {
                viewModel.upsert(item)
            }

        }).show()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show the code for the MainActivity?

Comment: @SomerandomITboy I have added MainActivity.kt

Comment: try giving 0dp both android:layout_width and android:layout_height to recyclerview